# Is Allah bounded by Time and Space?

Tags: allah, hadith-interpretation, time

> “And there is none like unto Him.”
>   **Quran Al-Ikhlas, 112: 4**
>
> And We have already created man and know what his nafs whispers to
>   him, and We are closer to him than [his] jugular vein
>
> **Quran : Qaf 50 16**

When it Says "**closer to him than [his] jugular vein** " i don't think physically. This is something beyond our comprehension.

But according to some hadiths Allah is bounded by time and space

> **Sahih Bukhari:Volume 9, Book 93, Number 586:** 
>     Narrated Abu Huraira:
>   **Allah's Apostle sa**id, "Every night when it is the last third of the
>   night, our Lord, the Superior, the Blessed, descends to the nearest
>   heaven and says: Is there anyone to invoke Me that I may respond to
>   his invocation? Is there anyone to ask Me so that I may grant him his
>   request? Is there anyone asking My forgiveness so that I may forgive
>   him?. "

- what is the need for descending to nearest(space) heavan every night(time) if he is closer to us then our jugular vein?

Answer (score 1):

The first quote in Allah in his attribute of *Al-Hakam* (judge) and the second in his attribute of *Al-Rahim*. That Allah is closer to us than we can know (jugular vein), yet also beyond us in space and time (nearest heaven) is only an inconsistency seen from our only too human aspect. Though the Quran is *uncreated*; that is itself divine; we are *created* beings and see only meanings themselves that are created, and thus have a measure of imperfection in them.

The Ash'arite Ulema considered Allah to be outside of this created world; that is outside our world bounded in time and in space; Heaven is not in space and time; for in time, which is one of the conditions of being in this world, all things decay - they are mortal. In Heaven - all is immortal.

Answer (score 0):

You should note that, unlike physical objects, Allah doesn't leave behind His previous position when descending as that goes against the concept of omnipresence, that He exists in every place and in every time.

But what underpins the concept of "descent" is the fact that His existence becomes less manifest in lower degrees of existence. This is according to the theory of Emanationism which I briefly discussed [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/12011/verse-hadith-that-says-allah-creates-out-of-nothing/12076#12076) while ago.

Comment: Since earth is round and some part of the world   always in last third of the night . By "His existence becomes less manifest in lower degrees of existence." do you mean Allah is permanently  less manifest in lower degrees of existence..

Comment: @ayub
Yes, unless there's a medium that can manifest Him stronger in that level. Such as a Prophet or a saint! Those who are enlightened by Him and subsequently illuminate others by His light.

Comment: Do you have any proof for this claim. Where does this medium stationed at earth or nearest heaven?

Comment: @ayub
Stationed? What do you mean? I already exemplified what I mean by a medium, a prophet or a saint. Recall the Quranic story where Allah manifested Himself onto a mount for Moses! Or When Gabriel appeared to Mary giving her Jesus, or reciting Quran to the Prophet! These are what I meant by God manifesting Himself *stronger*, otherwise His existence is normally visible to all: "So that they will see Our signs in the horizons and within themselves" or "Whichever direction you turn Allah's face is present" Holy Quran.

Comment: Then what is the purpose for descending to nearest heaven? the Quranic verse is clear "he is closer to us than our jugula vein"

Comment: @ayub, 
I already explained! God is omnipresent but not uniformly manifest at all levels and to all persons!

Comment: thank you for your answer. It is hard to fathom what you say. I'm not going to change my view "Allah is beyond our comprehension".

Comment: That's for sure!

Answer (score -3):

Allah is Time.
TIME=ALLAH

Creation is Space.
SPACE=CREATION

TIME & SPACE
ALLAH & ALL HIS CREATION

Comment: no no no. How could God be time? He is God Almighty who created the Universe, space and time.